# "Setting movie path"- from where it would be logged?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my log.Here my Current URL is the path of the mp3;when I load the Current URL in webview its automatically logged "setting movie path" and played in movie player.My question is where it is from? and I need to access this "setting movie path" url

```
Current URL:::http://isaitamil.in/download/file.php?p=0&file=files/2013/555/Mudhal%20Mazhai%20Kaalam.mp3&sort=0
2014-04-02 18:37:13.654 FileHandling[12476:60b] Start Loading
2014-04-02 18:37:23.010 FileHandling[12476:60b] setting movie path: http://isaitamil.in/download/files/2013/555/Mudhal%20Mazhai%20Kaalam.mp3
2014-04-02 18:37:34.763 FileHandling[12476:3d07] RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
```

I searched lot but I can't get a clear answer for this.Please help for me.....

Comment: This is from your website data. You can see it when you have source file of that website

Comment: Could you please help me to assign that url(setting movie path) to a variable?

Answer (score -2):

You will get the url of playing mp3/mp4 using this:
NSString *URL = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"];